Java Spring Boot JPA database connection issue
Im working on Java Spring Boot application, and have a problem with connection to database via JPA. JPA cannot connect to my db. I tried many url configurations, but connection failed and such exception shows:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Im using Microsoft SQL Server localdb. Here is my application.properties configuration
spring.application.name=Two4H
server.port=8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://.\\MSSQLLocalDB\\Two4H;integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

And this is my DB connection in IntelliJ which i would like to connect to my application:


What do you mean by "not working" ? What is happening ? Any error ?

"succeeded" in bright green lettering very much contradicts the statement "IntelliJ cannot connect to my db". It clearly can. You probably mean your Spring Boot application cannot. The JDBC url in the IntelliJ config seems very different from the one in the application.properties.

Yes, you are right, I should be more precise. IntelliJ can connect with this db, but JPA cannot. I tried different url's before (also the same as in connection tab) but it failed.
In console i have this exception:
Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://.\MSSQLLocalDB\Two4H;integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=true

Can you try using the following property?
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=Two4H;integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=true
or
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://(localdb)/MSSQLLocalDB;databaseName=Two4H;integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=true

I tried it and still have issues with this connection. I have this exception in connection tab:
[08S01] The connection to the host (localdb), named instance mssqllocaldb failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: (localdb)"

I fixed this problem. At first I use SQL Server 2022 Configuration Manager to set new local SQL Server and configure its TCP/IP protocol. Then I simply change URL in Spring Boot's application.properties to:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Two4H;integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=true

Here's a good article I found
https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server

For SQL server URL and driver class should be
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQLLocalDB:1433;database=Two4H;integratedSecurity=true;TrustServerCertificate=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver


Im using those drivers, but this url causes error:
[08S01] The TCP/IP connection to the host MSSQLLocalDB, port 1433 has failed.

To fix that error launch SQL Server Configuration Manager and in the right panel expand SQL network configuration and click on protocols. Make sure TCP/IP is enabled. And if it still doesn't work double click on it then go IP Addresses tab. Change all TCP Port values to 1433. Then come to SQL Services in the left pane and restart the SQL server.
